# How to assign a structure member to a variable in C

Tags: c, struct

Hi everyone i'm new in C and i want to know if it's possible to assign a structure member  to a variable in C like below

```
struct User
{
   int ID;
   char name[10]; 

}users[10];

int uid,
char userName;

uid = users[i].ID;
userName = user[i].name;
```

trying to do something like above i got a warning that "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"
and when compile i run since it was a warning not an error it run but then i can't print the value of uid or userName the system will just quit;
Please i know many will ask while can't i just access the structure member directly and print it i know i can do it that way but what i actually want to to do is to see a way i can assign the value to variable

Comment: Without seeing a [mcve] I can only *guess* that `user[i].name` is a *pointer* (i.e. `char * `)? A `char` is *not* the same as a `char *`.

Comment: well the question has very less details. but change the `char userName` to `char *userName` if the user[i].name is a string.

Comment: @ Revolver thanks for helping i will edit my question and post the structure

Comment: A name cannot be a single character. Member `name` is either a `char *` or a `char[]`. In both cases you cannot assign to a variable of type `char`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone your suggestion work right i define the variable name as a pointer and that solve the problem

Comment: You're trying to assign an array name, which in C is a equivalent to the pointer to the first element of itself, to a standard `char`. Simply modify this declaration `char userName;` to `char *userName;`, and then you can assign `userName = user[i].name;` without duplicating the string.

Answer (score 0):

The problematic statement is

```
userName = user[i].name;
  |            |
 char type   char array type
```

firstly `userName` is declared as **character** variable and a character variable can't holds `char array` i.e `user[i].name`.

Change this

```
char userName;
```

to

```
char userName[10];
```

and then copy using `strcpy()` or `strncpy()`. For e.g

```
strcpy(userName, user[i].name);
```

Comment: Never use strncpy (unless you have a very good reason that you can explain when asked about it). strncpy is a time bomb waiting to blow up in your face at any time.